# Changing a char array's values

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

```
char* foo = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char)*50); foo = "testing";
```

In C, i can see the first character of that string :

```
printf("%c",foo[0]);
```

But when i try to change that value :

```
foo[0]='f'
```

It gives error in runtime.

How can i change this, dynamically allocated, char array's values?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are setting foo to point to the string literal (`"testing"`) not the memory you allocated.  Thus you are trying to change the read only memory of the constant, not the allocated memory.

This is the correct code:

```
char* foo = malloc(sizeof(char)*50);
strcpy(foo,"testing");
```

or even better

```
cont int MAXSTRSIZE = 50;
char* foo = malloc(sizeof(char)*MAXSTRSIZE);
strncpy(foo,"testing",MAXSTRSIZE);
```

to protect against buffer over-run vulnerability.

Comment: Don't cast your malloc. char * foo = malloc( sizeof(char) * MAXSTR );

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that you are changing the pointer reference.

By doing :

```
char* foo = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char)*50); foo = "testing";
```

You are assigning the foo **pointer** to the `"testing"` string that is stored somewhere (hens the runtime error i guess), not to the newly allocated space.

Hope this will help

Answer (score 1):

With strings, you shouldn't assign their values via the assignment operator (`=`). This is because strings aren't an actual type, they are just char pointers. Instead, you have to use `strcpy`.

The problem with your code is that you have allocated memory for `foo`, then you reassign `foo` to a different memory address that is READONLY. When you assign to `foo[0]` you get a runtime error because you are trying to write to readonly memory.

Fix your code by doing this:

```
char* foo = malloc(50);
strcpy(foo, "testing");
```

This works because `foo` points to the address that you allocated.

Comment: If assigning a value to foo[0] means reassigning the variable, what does assigning a value to foo[1] mean?

Comment: @gcx -- the same thing this would just point at the `e` and not the `t` in the constant string.

Comment: No, `foo = "testing"` reassigns the variable to an address (different than the one that you allocated).